# find files under subdirectory using find in centos

Tags: centos6, cron, find

My current cronjob is

```
* 10 * * * /bin/find /var/spool/record/ -type f -exec /bin/rm {} +
```

It delete all files at 10 AM everyday .

I am trying to delete specific file of size less than 90KB type under current directory. for that

```
* 10 * * * /bin/find /var/spool/record/ -type f -iname "*.gsm" -size -90K -exec /bin/rm {} +
```

My concern is, will above syntax delete GSM files from subdirectory as well, which will get created under /var/spool/record/ everyday and keep record for that specific date . Like /var/spool/record/date1, /var/spool/record/date2 .

I also want to remove GSM file older than 60 days under /var/spool/record/ and its subdirectory as well on 10 of each month at 10 AM

```
* 10 10 * * /bin/find /var/spool/record/ -type f -iname "*.gsm" -mtime +60 -exec /bin/rm {} +
```

What would be correct syntax to del subdirectory and file as well which are older than 60 days .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cron you wrote will run every minute between 10:00 and 10:59. Use the following to fix that:

> 00 10 10 * * /bin/find /var/spool/record/ -type f -name "*.gsm" -mtime +60 -exec /bin/rm {} \;

This will delete .gsm files from /var/spool/record and its subdirectories which are older than 60 days at 10 AM and 10th of each month.

Comment: Thanks for correction. this syntax will delete GSM files older than 60 days from all subdirectory, but how can i delete subdirectory older than 60 days. My record directory contains some other directory as well including some PHP and webfiles . So i can't omit "-type f -name "*.gsm" .from above cron syntax or else it will delete everything under record directory . My subdirectory structure is like /record/201610/01, /record/2016/02 and so on for all dates for the current month, and these directory keeps record . These directory gets auto created depend on date and month .

Comment: My current direcotry hierarchy is like 
`/var/spool/record/webfiles (css, html,php)`
`/var/spool/record/201601`
`/var/spool/record/201602`
`/var/spool/record/201603 `
`/var/spool/record/index.php, style.css, .htaccess, .htpasswd`
If i implement any cronjob to del subdirectory older than 60 days it will aslo delete
record/webfiles direcotry as well . Any soltuion please

Comment: so the subdirectories you want to delete are always named in the format <year><month> right?